# How to Store Google Sign In User Data

Tags: single-sign-on, google-signin

I'm in the process of setting up Google Sign In / SSO.

My question is related how I would store the data collected, i.e. Email Address and Name.

For example, can I setup a Google Doc that captures the Email Address and Name?